# Java Android Studio Color Int to byte

Tags: java, android, colors, int, rgb

I want to convert an int color to a rgb byte array. I'm using the ColorPickerDialog ([ColorPickerDialog](http://android.okhelp.cz/color-picker-dialog-android-example/)).

If I select a color (lets say blue), I'll get the Integer value: -16775425.

This conforms to 0xFF 00 06 FF in hex.

To my knowledge its: Red: 0x0 , Green: 0x06, Blue: 0xFF.  If I test it in MS-Paint (0006FF), I'll get the blue color.

If I try to converte the integer value to a byte Array with following code:

```
public byte [] getColorByte(int color1){
    byte[] color = new byte[3];
    color[2] = (byte) (color1 & 0xFF);
    color[1] = (byte) ((color1 >> 8) & 0xFF);
    color[0] = (byte) ((color1 >> 16) & 0xFF);
    return color;
```

I'll get a byte Array with [0,6,-1].

But If I want to set the Background color of a button with the Color.rgb function:

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(getColorByte(color1)[0],getColorByte(int color1)[1],getColorByte(int color1)[2]));
```

I only get a white Button.

To my mind the problem is that 255 = FF != -1. Is that correct?
How can I split an Integer to the RGB-Values? (3 byte Array).

Thanks!!!

FYI: I know that I can change the Background color with the integer, but I want to get the RGB Array :-)

Comment: Try storing the colour array as an `int[]` rather than a `byte[]` so you don't get negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks, another question: how can I get back from the [0,6,-1] Byte Array to the -16775425 Int Value? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question (the one about converting the array back into an intger) the following code:

```
int answer = color[2];
answer += color[1] << 8;
answer += color[0] << 16;
```

This basically inverses your operation.

Comment: Thanks! But if I converte back like this, I'll get a positive integer. Not a negative .. Is there a way to get at signed value?

Comment: Have you tested it? It should still be a negative output

Comment: Yes, I testet it.. hmmm